# error: driver already registered, aborting

Tags: linux-device-driver, kernel-module

I compiled a (lm75) driver as a module to insert at run-time and and when tried to perform below

```
#insmod ./lm75.ko
```

I got the output as

```
Error: Driver 'lm75' is already registered aborting...  
insmod: can't insert './lm75.ko': Device or resource busy
```

So, tried removing the same from kernel as below

```
#rmmod lm75.ko
```

which outputted

```
rmmod: can't unload module 'lm75': No such file or directory
```

let me know if I'm missing something else?

Comment: `rmmod lm75` will do it if it's not busy.

Comment: Perhaps the driver is built into the kernel.  Have you checked the kernel config?

Comment: @IanAbbott I've tried the following command  `cat /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/modules.builtin`  from [link](http://superuser.com/questions/577307/how-to-get-a-list-of-active-drivers-that-are-statically-built-into-the-linux-ker) and I didn't get the lm75.ko in the list

Comment: What value of configuration option `SENSORS_LM75` for the running kernel? (Usually, there is `/boot/config-$(uname -r)` file which contains configuration).

Comment: I figured out the issue, as I'm using a script to run commands in u-boot which in turn is loading images (uImage, rootfs, dtb) from predefined locations in the MMC where as the recent version uImage is in wrong location. **Hence, the uImage and rootfs loaded are different whereas uImage has LM75.KO inserted (as it is a old image where LM75 is compiled as an built-in driver) and rootfs has no info about the LM75 (as it is latest one, in which LM75 is compiled as an kernel module)**. When, replaced with correct images the insmod and rmmod worked as expected. Thanks, for the responses & inputs :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using a script to run commands in u-boot which in turn is loading images (uImage, rootfs, dtb) from predefined locations in the MMC where as the recent version uImage is in wrong location (my fault). Hence, the uImage and rootfs loaded are different, whereas uImage has LM75.KO inserted (as it is a old image where LM75 is compiled as an built-in driver) and rootfs has no info about the LM75 (as it is latest one, in which LM75 is compiled as an kernel module). When, replaced with correct images the insmod and rmmod worked as expected. Hope this helps people like me :)